# Getting "shared memory ID" error on Linux

Tags: linux, memory, operating-system, shared-memory

Running this version of Linux:

```
Linux trhtmxslsp01b02 2.6.32-358.14.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Jun 17 15:54:20 EDT 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I attempt to start a process but getting the following error

```
OpenShmMemory(): Cannot get shared memory ID, No such file or directory.
```

The app/process I'm running read the shared memory segment. I don't know how to troubleshoot this. This is a third party app. Can someone provide some guidance please?

Comment: Start with running the app under `strace(1)`.

Comment: Hi Nikolai how do I run it with strace(1)? thx strace then the command?

Comment: `strace app args ...` is a good start, then actually reading `strace(1)` http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html manual page will get you further.

Comment: I ran few variation of the trace command and all I see is the same message  across saying that ot get shared memory ID, No such file or directory.

Comment: What allocates/maps that shared memory? Do you need another program running? Do you have permissions/limits to grab that amount of memory?

Comment: question 1 - I don't understand it. question 2 - I do not need another program running. Question 3 - where would the permission limit be set ?

Comment: here are the first few lines of the strace  [ Process PID=35882 runs in 32 bit mode. ]
open("/opt/reuters/SOFTWARE/dacs/lib/tls/i686/sse2/libncurses.so.5", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/opt/reuters/SOFTWARE/dacs/lib/tls/i686/libncurses.so.5", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/opt/reuters/SOFTWARE/dacs/lib/tls/sse2/libncurses.so.5", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/opt/reuters/SOFTWARE/dacs/lib/tls/libncurses.so.5", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/opt/reuters/SOFTWARE/dacs/lib/i686/sse2/

Comment: That's all from run-time linker/loader trying to bring in shared libraries. You want to look for `shmXXX` system calls failing. Also take a look at `man svipc` for an overview. For limits you want to check `ulimit -a`. Other then that, I cannot comment on my former employer brilliant software :)